# String manipulation and replace c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to manipulate replace the letter a with capitals but want to ignore 'a's within a word i.e. in the example below replace would not capitialise the A

the a at the beginning of a sentence should be replaced

How can i achieve this in c#`

```
    void Main()
{
    // Many text editors allow you to change the case of text which is selected by the cursor.
    // For example, in Notepad++, Ctrl, Shift + U switches text to uppercase, while Ctrl + U takes the text to lowercase.

    // In our editor, we want to cycle the options:
    // Lower -> Mixed -> Upper
    // (Upper -> Lower -> Mixed -> Upper -> Lower -> Mixed etc. etc.)

    // Part 1: Make these test cases work!

    LowerCaseSelectionsAreCapitalised();
    MixedCaseSelectionsAreTransformedIntoUpperCase();
    UpperCaseSelectionsAreTransformedIntoLowerCase();
    EmptyStringEdgeCaseShouldNotDoAnythingAsTextRelated();
    CharactersEdgeCaseShouldNotBeReplaced();
    SpacesShouldNotBeReplaced();
    OneCharacterInstancesShouldBeReplaced();

    // Part 2: Write tests to make sure that edge cases are handled.
    //   Examples:
    //     What happens when no selection is made?
    //     What happens when a selection is one character long?
}

static int count = 0;


    private void LowerCaseSelectionsAreCapitalised()
    {
    Test("In this sentence, after transformation, dave should have a capital letter at the start of      the word.",
        "dave",
        "In this sentence, after transformation, Dave should have a capital letter at the start of the word.");
    }

    private void MixedCaseSelectionsAreTransformedIntoUpperCase()
{
    Test("Next, Dave should be all caps.",
        "Dave",
        "Next, DAVE should be all caps.");
}

private void UpperCaseSelectionsAreTransformedIntoLowerCase()
{
    Test("After another press of the shortcut, DAVE should be back to lowercase.",
        "DAVE",
        "After another press of the shortcut, dave should be back to lowercase.");
}

private void EmptyStringEdgeCaseShouldNotDoAnythingAsTextRelated()
{
    Test("After another press of the shortcut, DAVE should be back to lowercase.",
         "",
        "After another press of the shortcut, dave should be back to lowercase.");
}

private void CharactersEdgeCaseShouldNotBeReplaced()
{
    Test("Exclamation Mark should not be replaced!",
         "!",
        "Exclamation Mark should not be replaced!");
}

private void ExclamationCaseShouldNotBeReplaced()
{
    Test("After another press of the shortcut, DAVE should be back to lowercase.",
         "!",
        "After another press of the shortcut, dave should be back to lowercase.");
}

private void SpacesShouldNotBeReplaced()
{
        Test("Spaces in this sentence should not be replaced",
         " ",
        "Spaces in this sentence should not be replaced");
}

private void OneCharacterInstancesShouldBeReplaced()
{

    Console.WriteLine("here");
    Test("the a at the beginning of a sentence should be replaced",
         "a",
         "the A At the beginning of A sentence should be replaced");
}

private void Test(string input, string wordToAdjust, string expected)
{
    var indexWordToAdjust = input.IndexOf(wordToAdjust);
    var indexBefore = indexWordToAdjust - 1;

    if (indexWordToAdjust > 0 && !Char.IsSeparator(input, indexWordToAdjust))
    {
            CycleCase(input,indexWordToAdjust , wordToAdjust.Length).Should().Be(expected);
    }
}

public string CycleCase(string sentence, int selectionIndex, int selectionLength)
{
    string newSentence = "";
    var word = sentence.Substring(selectionIndex, selectionLength);

    //switch count 
    switch(count){

        case 0: {
                string backx;
                var convertToUpper = word.First().ToString().ToUpper() + word.Substring(1); //to upper case     
                for(var i =0; i < word.Length; i++)
                {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(backx);
                sentence[i + selectionIndex] = word[i];
                backx = sb.ToString();

                }
                //newSentence = sentence.Replace(word, convertToUpper); 
                break;          
        }
        case 1: {

                var mixCase = word.ToString().ToUpper(); //MIX  
                for(var i =0; i < word.Length; i++)
                {
                    sentence[i + selectionIndex] = word[i];
                }                       
                break;  
        }
        case 2: {
            var toLower = word.ToString().ToLower();            
            for(var i =0; i < word.Length; i++)
                {
                    sentence[i + selectionIndex] = word[i];
                }
            break;
        }
        default:
            return null;

    }


    count++;
    if (count > 2) { count = 0; }
    return newSentence;
}
```

Comment: Any effort so far? It doesn't sound a hard problem.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string.Split`, `LINQ` and `String.Join`:

```
str = string.Join(" ", str.Split()
    .Select(w => w.StartsWith("a") ? "A" + w.Substring(1) : w));
```

But note that this simple approach also replaces new-line characters (or tabs) with a simple space.